# Display multiple instances of a model as a table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

For displaying one instance of my model, I am displaying it like,

tags_file.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def as_table(model):
    ret = ""
    for name in model._meta.get_all_field_names():
        try:
            field = str(getattr(model, name))
            if field:
                ret += '<tr><td class="name">'+name+'</td><td class="field">'+field+'</td></td>'
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return ret
```

display.html

```
{% load tags_file %}
<table>
    {{output|as_table|safe}}
</table>
```

views.py

```
return render_to_response('display.html',
                              {'output': obj,})
```

This displays one instance of my model, 'obj'.
But if I want to display multiple instances of my model, like if I have obj1, obj2, obj3, how do I display them in a tabular format?

Comment: Are you looking for a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)?..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of object and then iterate over it:

```
return render_to_response('display.html',
                          {'outputs': [obj1, obj2, obj3],})
```

And then in the template:

```
{% for obj in outputs %}
    {{ obj|as_table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```